# Sphero Chromo functionality

Tags: sphero-api

I'm trying to get my Sphero to lock in place like it does when used as a controller in the Sphero "Chromo" app on iTunes. It locks the internals in place and uses gyroscope readings, but I cannot figure out how to get it to stay in place.

```
Windows 8.1 SDK
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the internal robot does not self-level to heavy side down?
Turn stabilisation off. Thats the recommended setting when using sphero as an input controller plus you save battery:)

This can be tested quite easily with their macro app: 
- Turn off stabilisation and change LED to red
- Delay for 10 seconds
- Turn on stabilisation and don't bother setting LED colour as the macro ends and reverts to default colour.

During those 10 seconds in delay see what happens when you move the sphere in your hand.

Comment: Indeed. The Windows 8.1 SDK handles basic connectivity and handling, but not much else. I figured it out around four AM. Thank you for your response.